# How to remove space between table rows displayed as inline-block?

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-tables

I was following this example of responsive tables :
http://dbushell.com/demos/tables/rt_05-01-12.html

but I have a weird space between table rows displayed as inline-block, here's a demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Fksjw

I tried zeroing out the margins but I can't get rid of this space.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle? your codepen appears empty for me..

Comment: @Nelson here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/W2ACD/

Comment: I see space between columns, not between rows, is the former what you want to avoid?

Comment: @Nelson the columns are the tr tags, and yes that's what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you see is the default behaviour of inline (inline-block) elements. One possible solution is to set `font-size` and `line-height` to 0 to make white spaces invisible. Then you just reset them back to some values:

```
tbody {
    ...
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
}
tbody td {
    ...
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W2ACD/1/

Another solution would be manually remove *all* the line breaks and spaces between `tr`.

Comment: Thank you both solutions worked fine, but why line breaks are causing this ?

Comment: @Peter This is described [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-model).

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your css:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tbody tr {
   display: table-row;
}

tbody td {
   display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for, I need the table rows to be displayed as inline-block and the td as block, to make the table show without breaking the layout on small screens.

Answer (score 0):

The Inline-block elements always give 3 pixels of extra margin. You can solve it subtracting 3 pixel for each horizontal side:

```
tbody tr {
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0 -3px;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```